# What is the expected behaviour of a shrinking scrollable Container?

Tags: codenameone

With Codename One components can change their size and this even can be animated, which is nice.

But what is the expected behaviour with shrinking Container instances, specifically if they are scrollable?

Having a Container, scrollable in the Y-axis and content that is smaller than the container the content sticks to the top. The container can be dragged and the content scrolls back to the top of the container. However, when the content shrinks and becomes smaller than the container the behaviour is - somewhat strange.

I have made an example - when the coloured components are tapped they expand. If tapped again they shrink. One can tap the green Label and it expands. Tapping it again it shrinks and everything is as of before.

[image]

However, if one taps a coloured label and scrolls any amount down before tapping it again to shrink it this is the resulting view:

[image]

Only if one then drags the scrolling container ever so lightly then the contant scrolls back to the top.

I assume this is a bug. Though I wonder - what should be the behaviour when the content shrinks beyond the scrolling containers size? Since the user might expect the component just tapped to remain where it was - can the scrolling behaviour be controlled somehow?

This is just an example but I want to build expandable "drawer" components.

Here is the code:

```
public class FormContentSmallerScrollableContainer extends Form {

    private class LabelExpandable extends Label {
        boolean expanded = false;
        LabelExpandable(String aTitle, int aColor) {
            super(aTitle);
            getAllStyles().setBgPainter((aGraphics, aRectangle) -> {
                aGraphics.setColor(aColor);
                aGraphics.fillRoundRect(getX(), getY(), aRectangle.getWidth() - 1, aRectangle.getHeight() - 1, 20, 20);
            });
            setOpaque(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
            super.pointerReleased(x, y);
            expanded = !expanded;
            setShouldCalcPreferredSize(true);
            getParent().animateLayout(400);
        }

        @Override
        protected Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
            if (!expanded) {
                return super.calcPreferredSize();
            }
            Dimension dimension = super.calcPreferredSize();
            dimension.setHeight(Display.getInstance().getDisplayHeight());
            return dimension;
        }
    }

    public FormContentSmallerScrollableContainer() {
        super("FormContentSmallerScrollableContainer");
        setScrollable(false);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new Label("The container below is scrollable in the y-axis"));
        Container containerScrollable = BoxLayout.encloseY(
                new LabelExpandable("LabelExpandable green", 0x00ff00),
                new LabelExpandable("LabelExpandable blue", 0x00c0ff));
        containerScrollable.setScrollableY(true);
        add(BorderLayout.CENTER, containerScrollable);
        add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, new Label("The container above is scrollable in the y axis"));
    }

}
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1998

Answer (score 1):

This is a long standing behavior when we animate a scrollable area to what's effectively a non-scrollable area. We tried working around this in the past but couldn't find the right approach. You can file the issue on this but I'm not optimistic as it's really hard to even find a workaround for this.

Comment: Well I cannot live with that behaviour and that is one of the reasons why I discontinued my subscription and my app in which I've had put a lot of effort into. But I cannot help myself and put Your nose on it. I really would apreciate if Codename One would become useable for me. I cannot help with the internals but I am prepared to put in some time as a tester and even investigate it as far as I can to bring things forward. What I cannot do is really use Codename One and deliver something that doesn't meet my standards. That would drive me crazy which I prefer to avoid but still am so sorry.

Comment: If You allowed me to override or overshadow Codename One code that resides on the build server I could pick up on it again. Of course and in my own interest I would keep that to the minimum. You'd gain a chance on getting more attention through my success. I know your points of view, but you have nothing to lose by letting me have my way - the only way I can do it since I have limited time. Is there any chance You let my override Codename One classes just for my projects as a last resort when I cannot get You to fix bugs? Not beeing able to fix things drives me to despair.

Comment: If you leap over your shadow, I could gain confidence in advancing my projects and, who knows, perhaps even get into investing more time supporting Codename One directly. As things are now, I can not recommend Codename One in good conscience.

Comment: Kind words help solve problems constructively. Shai suggested you to file the issue on https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues, that is the first step. If you want to try to fix this issue by yourself, you can fork the Codename One Github repository and compile your project against your fork, fix the bug and then submit a Pull Request. About the build servers, if you prefer not to be forced to use them, see the section "Building from the Open Source Project Offline Without Build Servers or Plugin" in the Codename One Academy.

Comment: This is about a very old misbehaviour for which I filed an issue years ago. I filed a lot of issues. Many of those have been closed with no good reason hence my resignation. There are bugs I cannot provide a pull request for. What II can do is report those issues. But I cannot wait for years passing by and nothing happens. Then, at least I need to be able to overshadow framework classes until a fix for the public becomes available. But I’m afraid I haven’t got all the time that would be necessary to follow Shai’s or Your advice.

Comment: I added a new Issue https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2840